# How do I correctly add this action to the right click menu in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-registry

In `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell` and `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` I have created the Primary Key "Serve Directory". Then added the "command" key under this primary key, which contains `"C:\Users\assylum\Documents\_Scripts\ruby_webserver.cmd" "%1"` as the `Default` entry. The content of this batch file is `ruby -run -e httpd %1 -b 127.0.0.1 -p 4000`.

Here is an image to explain this better:

[image: Image of Registry Folder Structure]

[image: Image Registry with Command]

When I right click on a folder, this works fine. However, if I right click into the white space of a folder and choose the command, I get this error message:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

What is my mistake here?

Comment: If you switch it to a program like notepad does it work?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, it does. However, same command works when right-clicking a folder too. It is just the "global" entry that causes issues. Prepending it with `cmd.exe /C` does not help either.

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps try relocating "ruby_webserver.cmd" (etc.) to someplace outside of your user folder, to a folder that all users can access, and try it again?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Moved it to `C:\Tools` edited both entries, same difference.

Comment: I would suggest the next thing to check is if Explorer is puking when it tries to the `ruby_webserver.cmd` file, or if it's when it tries to run a command within the .cmd file.   Perhaps test by replacing `ruby_webserver.cmd` with another .cmd that simply echoes something to a file, or alike? If that works as expected, then it's probably something _in_ the .cmd that need sot be looked at next.

Comment: As I said, the batch file works when I right click a folder. Here is a video: https://streamable.com/m2t9s The Ruby bin directory is in the path for all users, so Windows should find it no problem. Also, the command window should still open for a second, if it cannot find the command in the batch file.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I added `echo Test > file.txt` as a first line, the file does not show up when reproducing the issue, so Windows somehow does not know how to launch a .cmd file, even though the ending is in the `PATHEXT`variable.

Comment: Does it happen to work if you use a `.bat` instead?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Same thing. Also changing it to `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /C "C:\tools\ruby_webserver.cmd" "%1"`does not work either.